# How to pass CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME value to python script from aws buildspec.yaml

Tags: python-3.x

I need to pass `CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME` value from buildspec.yml to a python script. I tried to pass using $CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME$ and @CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME@ to python but in python script I am getting what ever I am passing i.e. $CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME$ or @CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME@. Python script is not getting the value of `CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME`.

buildspec.yml is as below.

```
post_build:
    commands:
      - python test.py --name=$CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME$
```

Can someone please let me know how to pass the value of a variable from buildspec.yml to python.